# How to make a live post request first promoter affiliate using js

Tags: javascript, affiliate

Hello I am working on a project that requires me to track pages using first promoter.

see below api documentation

`https://docs.firstpromoter.com/#api-reference`

what i need to do is get the present cookie of the website and pass the "vistior tracking id" as below using the link and  js.

```
https://######.com?fpr=testvstihyao&test_mode=1`

<script>(function(w){w.fpr=w.fpr||function(){w.fpr.q = w.fpr.q||[];w.fpr.q[arguments[0]=='set'?'unshift':'push'](arguments);};})(window);
fpr("init", {cid:"######"}); 
fpr("click");
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.firstpromoter.com/fpr.js" async></script>

<script>
var x = document.cookie; 
window.alert(x);    

</script>
```

also see screenshots of request made

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjHCJ.png)

and then I make a request to using first promoters documentation as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzSUE.png)

so everything works while testing.

But when i try to track my page like this https://######.com?fpr=dee.   (without the test mode i am unable to get a tid which I am supposed to use to make an api request.

I was expecting to get the tid when i tried to access the cookie with the tesmode parameter

I must be missing something, please help